# Attaching a folder to an existing calendar entry using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add a folder as an attachment to an existing calendar event.

This is the code I have so far

```
var clientEvent = myEvent
var calendarId = myCalendar
var calendarResource = {
        attachments: [{
       'folderID': clientFolder.getId()
        }]
                        };
Calendar.Events.patch(calendarResource, calendarID , clientEvent.getId(), {"supportsAttachments": true});
```

Comment: I suggest you add more tags to your question, so more people will see it. The [calendar] tag alone may not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot add a folder as an event attachment, only documents can be added

- You can either add all the documents contained in the folder as attachments (can be done dynamically with a loop)
- Or simply provide the link to the folder within the event description (you would need to update the [access permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) to provide access to all the event attendees)